# ¿Cómo puedo validar un formulario en AngularJs al momento enviarlo?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Soy novato en AngularJs y necesito que se me valide un formulario al momento en el que el usuario selecciona "Enviar" (y no a medida que vaya completando los campos).
Para resumir el formulario, en este ejemplo solo muestro un mensaje si el usuario no ingresa ningún nombre. El código que tengo es el siguiente.

**En mi HTML**

```
    <body ng-app="miApp" ng-controller="miCtrl">
     <form ng-submit="aceptarPaciente()" name="f" novalidate>
          <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre (*)" ng-model="paciente.nombre" ng-required="true">
               <div class="messages" ng-show="f.nombre.$invalid && f.nombre.$touched">
                     <strong>Se debe ingresar un nombre</strong>
               </div>
          <button type="submit">Aceptar</button>
          <button type="button" ng-click="limpiarPaciente(f)">Limpiar</button>
     </form>
</body>
```

**En mi Controlador**

```
    angular.module("miApp",[])
    .controller("miCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.limpiarPaciente = function(f) {
    $scope.paciente = {}; 
    };
    $scope.aceptarPaciente() {
    }})
```

Como dije antes, el código funciona a medida que el usuario rellena los campos pero no es lo que estoy necesitando.

El $scope.aceptarPaciente del controlador lo deje vacío porque es ahí donde tengo que hacer la validación (o por lo menos es lo que creo).

Nota: Para la solución de este problema, ya no iría el **f.nombre.$touched**  que ingresé ya que no tendría sentido esto porque el evento que se ejecutará si los campos están bien (o no) es el **ng-submit="aceptarPaciente()"**

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo logro de esta forma:

```
<form #formulario = 'ngForm' (ngSubmit) = 'onSubmit()' class="col-lg-6" >
      <!--Aqui tus campos-->
      <input type="submit" value="{{titulo}}" [disabled] = '!formulario.form.valid' class='btn btn-success' >
</form>
```

El botón no se habilita hasta que todos los campos son correctos.

Comment: Claro, esa sería otra solución pero no es lo que estoy buscando. El problema mio consiste en que el botón ''Enviar'' siempre esté habilitado, y que los mensajes que se muestren con **class="messages"** aparezcan si existe algún tipo de error.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizarlo de ésta manera, se va a ejecutar posterior al submit.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="form" ng-app>
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.email.$invalid]">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Your email address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required />
            <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.required">Required</span>
            <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
</form>
```